# Using combineByKey to add corresponding values of a list

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can I use combineByKey in scala to add multidimensional tuple in scala

```
val inputrdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("maths", (50,2)), ("maths", (60,1)), ("english", (65,2)), ("physics", (66,3)), ("physics", (60,2)), ("physics", (87,1))))
```

such that I receive ouput as :
(english,65,2),(maths,110,3) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use `combineByKey` here. It can be easily handled by simple `reduce`:

```
inputrdd
  .reduceByKey{case ((x1, x2), (y1, y2)) => (x1 + y1, x2 + y2)}
  .map{case (k, (v1, v2)) => (k, v1, v2)}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use reduceByKey instead:

```
inputrdd.reduceByKey((x:(Int,Int), y:(Int,Int)) => (x._1+y._1,x._2+y._2))
 inputrdd.collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

Below the solution using combineByKey

```
    inputrdd.combineByKey((x:(Int,Int))=>(x._1,x._2),(u:(Int,Int),v:(Int,Int))=>(u._1+v._1,u._2+v._2),(acc1:(Int,Int),acc2:(Int,Int))=>(acc1._1+acc2._1,acc1._2+acc2._2)).collect
   res135: Array[(String, (Int, Int))] = Array((maths,(110,3)), (physics,(213,6)), (english,(65,2)))
```